# Visual studio - open 2 windows

Tags: c#, windows, window

I want to know if it's possible to create 2 windows into the visual editor of VS ?

I have to do something like this :

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: WPF or WindowsForm or .. what platform ?

Comment: I think it's windows form, i'm under Windows

Comment: WPF stands for Windos Presentation Fundation, so I'm pretty sure you can use it under windows hehehe